# Why is the osmotic force virtual?

Tags: thermodynamics, brownian-motion, randomness, osmosis

In [Einstein's treatment of Brownian motion](https://web.math.princeton.edu/~nelson/books/bmotion.pdf) he argues that (in equilibrium) there is an "osmotic pressure force" $\vec O$ that counterbalances the effect of gravity $\vec K$.

[image]

This allows him to derive the relation
\begin{align}
\vec K &= \vec O \\
&= kT \frac{\nabla n}{n} ,
\end{align}
where $n$ is the particle density. Einstein [emphasized](https://books.google.dk/books?id=X5iRDQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA59&ots=-VW0h98xyl&dq=%22osmotic%20%22%20%22virtual%20force%22&hl=de&pg=PA58#v=onepage&q&f=false) that the osmotic pressure force is entirely virtual.

---

*In what sense is the osmotic pressure force virtual? And how can the formula 
$$ \vec O =kT \frac{\nabla n}{n} $$
be derived?*